# How can I calculate a hash for a struct containing raw Value in tandem with serde-json library

Tags: rust, traits, serde

I need my structs to be hashable. The structs never mutate after creation so it could be possible to pre-calculate and store it as a field.

An example struct looks like this:

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct Predicate {
    note: Option<String>,
    arguments: Option<HashMap<String, Value>>,
    value: Value,
}
```

I tried to add `Hash` directive to the struct , but `Value` doesn't implement `Hash`

tried to implement myself

`impl Hash for Value {`

but getting error

```
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-----
    | |             |
    | |             `Value` is not defined in the current crate
    | impl doesn't use only types from inside the current crate
```

so 2 possible solutions would suffice for me

1. calculate and store the hash on deserialization and save as a field of the struct (which never changes)
2. Implement `Hash` on `Value` - but not sure it is possible to do outside of of the `serde` crate.

Option 1 could work for me (calculate + store during deserialize)

I saw in the documentation https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#deserialize_with

`#[serde(deserialize_with = "path")]`

but didn't see any example how it can be done

Maybe there are other approaches?

Comment: It's hard to auto implement hashing of arbitrary JSON (as you try by implementing `Hash` on `Value`)

Comment: What is `Value`?

Answer (score 0):

Since `HashMap` and `Value` both don't implement `Hash` your best bet is to manually implement `Hash` for `Predicate` manually. To reduce repetition, I also recommend making a  wrapper around `Value` and implementing hash for that. When you do this, make sure that if `a == b` then `a_hashed == b_hashed`. Sample code:

```
impl Hash for Predicate{
  fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, hasher:&mut H){
    self.note.hash(hasher);
    self.arguments.iter().for_each(|(key,value)|{  
      //Without realizing it, I accidentally violated the contract I mentioned above
      //Because there is no guarantee about the order of items returned by HashMap.iter().
      //Thanks, @Jmb for pointing it out. Let this serve as a warning, be really 
      //Careful when manually implementing Hash and similar traits.
      key.hash(hasher);
      MyValue(value).hash(hasher);    
    });
    MyValue(self.value).hash(hasher);
  }    
}

struct MyValue(Value);
impl Hash for MyValue{
  fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, hasher:&mut H){
    //large match statement here
  }
}
```

The OP mentioned that they could guarantee that the objects would be created once and not mutated. If that's the case, you could instead add a unique identifier, such as from the [UUID Crate](https://docs.rs/uuid/0.8.2/uuid/) or a timestamp of creation and hash that instead of the much more expensive full hash.

Comment: Any way to cache the hash value or calculate on deserialization once? I will need to hash this many times

Comment: Note that `HashMap` makes no guaranties on item order when you iterate, so you can't be sure that two equal predicates will have the same hash.

Comment: @Jmp added a disclaimer/warning

Comment: @AvnerBarr Hashing some sort of unique identifier is probably what you want.